# Using keyboard events with textareas

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, textarea

I am making a basic online editor using text area, i would like the editor to listen to keydown events. I have tried to make the code listen to the tab key pressed and then add space (4spaces) between the textcontent but it doesn't work. How can i go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

  <script>
  document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

  function logKey(key){
    if (key.keyCode == "9"){
        myTextArea.textContent += '    ';
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <div class="navBar" id="heading-container"></div>
</header>
  <textarea id="myTextArea">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent semper in nunc at mattis. Suspendisse metus augue, pellentesque finibus luctus dictum, tempor id nunc.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I'm not pressing Tab at the **end** of the textarea? I **strongly** recommend that you don't try to reinvent this wheel. Use CodeMirror or similar.

Comment: try with keypress event.

Comment: you also need to cancel the action

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems there:

1. `keyCode` is a key **code**, not a character, which is a number.For the Tab key, use `keyCode === 9`. This is one of the reliable key codes (not all key codes are across different keyboard layouts, etc.).
2. You're doing `.value += '    '`, which will do this:

   - Take all text from the textarea
   - Add `'    '` to the **end** of it (regardless of where the insertion point was when the user pressed Tab)
   - Replace all text in the textarea with the updated string, moving the insertion point to the beginning of it or the end of it depending on the browser
3. You're listening for Tab on `document`, not just within the textarea
4. Your `script` is in the `head`, making it hard to fix #3. Normally, any non-`async`, non-`defer`, non-module script should be at the end of `body`, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.
5. You're relying on the automatic global for `myTextArea`. Although the creation of those automatic globals is standardized now, I **strongly** recommend not relying on them. Look up the elements you need using DOM APIs.
6. You probably want to prevent the default action of the Tab keypress.

#2 in particular will make a fairly poor user experience.

If you really want to do this, read up on [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) for #2. Example (also fixes the others mentioned):

```js
document.getElementById("myTextArea").addEventListener("keydown", handleKey); // #3, #5

function handleKey(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 9) { // #1
      document.execCommand("insertText", true, "    "); // #2
      event.preventDefault();                           // #6
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" cols=30 rows=10>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent semper in nunc at mattis. Suspendisse metus augue, pellentesque finibus luctus dictum, tempor id nunc.</textarea>
<!--
Stack Snippets handle #4 for you, by putting
the script after the HTML
-->
```

---

But as I said in a comment, I **strongly** recommend using something that's already been built and tested, like CodeMirror.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to the one given below :

```
   if (key.keyCode == "9"){
       key.preventDefault();
       myTextArea.value += '    ';
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     function logKey(key){
    if (key.keyCode == "9"){
        myTextArea.textContent += '    ';
        key.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

> Closing Tag is good habbit of coder..
>   Don't forget to close < textarea >